# Correct asset naming for image SEO

Tags: seo, images

This question is about image SEO.

**Background:**

I'm a server-side dev dabbling in SEO. I maintain a social web application where users submit interesting images (mostly memes, motivational quotes, poetry and nature photography). A ranked feed shows the best ones in list format.

I read that descriptive image names and alt tags are critical for image SEO (i.e. ranking highly in image search). To enable this, I analyze each image submitted on my web app and deduce its content.

For instance, if it's a meme related to the current social distancing guidelines, I'll set the image's alt tag to `social distancing meme`. Moreover, I'll name the image `social-distancing-meme-0f90a543-a77a-4b54-a0e3-7f5e17963891.jpg`. Lastly, I'll list the said image's webpage in a sitemap, which is available for Google et al.

Note that the image name created above contains a [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) (in addition to the words `social-distancing-meme`).

Why? Because tons of social distancing memes are submitted to the web app. I need to give them all distinct names. Appending a `uuid` to the image name guarantees uniqueness.

**The question:**

Now my question is: is image SEO going to take a hit because of an image naming scheme such as this? What's the best practice to follow for a case like mine?

I'm looking for an opinion regarding how industry experts would have tackled image SEO for a social app like mine. Thanks in advance.